# Oracle Entity creates only one table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework, web-config

I have trouble with code First Migrations with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 6.122.18.3` provider.

The Entity Frameworks creates the first table in the Oracle Database, but no more tables for the other models in the same Datacontext.

**My Web.config:**

```
 <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
           description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" 
           type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="OFAD" descriptor="... " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DbContext" 
     providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=..." />
```

My DbContext:

```
public DbContext() : base("name=DbContext")
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SCHEMANAME");
        }
```

The error message:

```
Exception Details: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

[OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist]
   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone) +647
   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF) +14595
   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior) +3483
   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +168
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +14
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +402
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +166
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +36

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +103
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +758
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6() +90
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +154
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +14
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +283
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +387
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
```

My nuget packages:

```
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="18.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" version="18.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: Maybe try a more stable (i.e. older, for example 12.2) version of the ODP.NET managed driver.

Comment: I tried, but got the same result. It creates the first DbSet in the DbContext, the others are not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have permission to create triggers, and I degraded OracleManagedDataAccess to 12.2.1100 and finally works.

The same result at the Oracle forum: [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4147335?start=15&tstart=0).